# Installing OpenCL for SVGA II Adapter

Tags: drivers, 16.04, package-management, gpu, opencl

I'm trying to run a program that uses OpenCL, however I'm running into an error:

> beignet-opencl-icd: no supported GPU found, this is probably the wrong
> opencl-icd package for this hardware

So it seems I might have the wrong version of OpenCL installed, here is is my info:

> root@ubuntu:~/Documents/project3.5/dataviz-dev/graphiti# lshw -C video
> *-display
>
> ```
>    description: VGA compatible controller
>    product: SVGA II Adapter
>    vendor: VMware
>    physical id: f
>    bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.0
>    version: 00
>    width: 32 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>    configuration: driver=vmwgfx latency=64
>    resources: irq:16 ioport:1070(size=16) memory:ec000000-efffffff memory:fe000000-fe7fffff memory:c0000000-c0007fff
> ```

I can't find to seem to find the appropriate steps to take to install OpenCL correctly on this machine. Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: `vendor: VMware` - are you trying to install this on a virtual machine?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, I was able to install it on a different virtualbox, but am having trouble with VMware

Comment: What ICDs do you have installed?

Comment: can't figure out how to check @fakedad

Comment: Try `ls /etc/OpenCL/vendors/`. That should output a list of the icd files in the ICD registry.

Comment: that returned: intel64.icd , intel-beignet-x86_64-linux-gnu.icd ,  intel.icd , nvidia.icd. The first one was highlighted in light blue. @fakedad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996996/trying-to-install-opencl-on-vm), the Intel SDK does not work on VMWare. It suggests instead trying to use the AMD APP SDK, which can be downloaded from [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/). The APP SDK can be installed by untarring and running the only shell script included in the download.

Comment: Thanks! I got it installed, however, do you happen to know how to set it as default? Looks like it's still using intel64.icd in /etc/OpenCL/vendors/

Comment: Since the Intel SDK doesn't work, removing it altogether by removing the associated packages  should force whatever application you are using to use the AMD APP SDK. However, I don't know if there is a guarantee that the application you are trying to run will work with the AMD APP SDK. Apart from that solution, I wouldn't know how to change the default. I'm honestly not too familiar with OpenCL.